# Receive formatted 'multipart/form-data' response in Angular 7.x

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, http-post, multipart

I am developing an Angular application that shows some images to the user.

I would like to obtain those images from a single REST call to a web service: given the fact i am already uploading the images via a `FormData` object, i would like to  receive those images in the same way (so, basically, via `content-type: multipart/form-data`).

At the moment, using the following code:

```
this.http.post('api/load', {}, {headers: {'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'},
  responseType:'text', observe: 'response'});
```

i am actually receiving the full body of the response in a text format, like this:

```
--974b5730-ab25-4554-8a69-444664cab379
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=result

{"bar":[1,2,3,4], "foo": true}
--974b5730-ab25-4554-8a69-444664cab379
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=image; filename=image1.jpg; filename*=utf-8''image1.jpg    
--- binarycontent...
```

But it's in a raw, text format.

How can i receive a `multipart/form-data` response formatted by its boundaries, or a in clean way in Angular 7.x?

Comment: Response you posted looks more like request. Why do you need to process it in Angular (which is front-end framework) ? It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to process the response of that request. The request will be a simple `application/json`, but the response will be a `multipart/form-data` (the server is already configured to so).
In other words, i am trying to download multiple images directly from a REST call

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to implement an interceptor service where you can format multipart/form-data response.
For example, your inteceptor will be  - **multipart.interceptor.ts** :

```js
@Injectable()
export class MultipartInterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {
    
    private parseResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>): HttpResponse<any> {
        const headerValue = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
        const body = response.body;
        const contentTypeArray = headerValue ? headerValue.split(';') : [];
        const contentType = contentTypeArray[0];

        switch (contentType) {
            case 'multipart/form-data':
                if (!body) {
                    return response.clone({ body: {} });
                }

                const boundary = body?.split('--')[1].split('\r')[0];
                const parsed = this.parseData(body, boundary); // function which parse your data depends on its content (image, svg, pdf, json)

                if (parsed === false) {
                    throw Error('Unable to parse multipart response');
                }

                return response.clone({ body: parsed });
            default:
                return response;
        }
    }

    // intercept request and add parse custom response
    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(customRequest).pipe(
            map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    return this.parseResponse(response);
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```